# Binding for property (looking for alternate syntax)

Tags: wpf, xaml

For reasons that would take way too long to explain (sorry), I'm trying to figure out if there are any alternate syntaxes for specifying attributes for objects in a XAML file.

Let's say I've got an ellipse like so:

```
<Ellipse (bunch of other attributes) Fill="{Binding EllipseFillColor}"/>
```

Is there any way to do something like this?

```
<Ellipse (bunch of other attributes)>
   <Fill Binding="EllipseFillColor"/>
</Ellipse>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, this kind of syntax is not supported, see: [XAML Syntax In Detail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

> XAML is a language based on XML and follows or expands upon XML structural rules. Some of the terminology is shared from or is based on the terminology commonly used when describing the XML language or the XML document object model.

There is the [*Attribute Syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#attribute-syntax-properties) for properties that you already know:

```
<Ellipse Fill="{Binding EllipseFillColor}"/>
```

Alternatively, there is the [*Property Element Syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#property-element-syntax), which is closer, but different:

```
<Ellipse>
   <Ellipse.Fill>
      <Binding Path="EllipseFillColor"/>
   </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

By the way, `Ellipse` and `Binding` use the [*Object Element Syntax*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-syntax-in-detail?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#object-element-syntax).